# PHP - Help Needed Creating Array in a Loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm processed some JSON data that is sent via HTTP POST to my PHP file. I then need to extract some elements and create a PHP array containing these, so I can then loop through this array and perform some actions.

Here's a sample of how the JSON data that is sent looks:

```
[
  {
    "fileName": "Invoices", 
    "event": "processed", 
    "serverName": "server1.acme.com", 
    "timestamp": 1574229999
  }, 
  {
    "fileName": "Invoices", 
    "event": "processed", 
    "serverName": "server2.acme.com", 
    "timestamp": 1574228341
  },
  {
    "fileName": "Payments", 
    "event": "processed", 
    "hostname": "server3.acme.com", 
    "timestamp": 1574766997
  }
]
```

I'm then decoding this to parse out just the elements I need:

```
$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$records= json_decode( $payload, FALSE ); 

$sessionsArray = array();

foreach($records as $record){

        $hostname = $record->hostname;
        $fileName = $record->fileName;
        // need to add these to the $sessionsArray for each iteration of the loop

}
```

I would like to create a new array `$sessionsArray` and add the $hostname and $fileName variables to this for each iteration in the foreach loop. I then intend to do another `foreach` on the `$sessionsArray` and perform some actions using the $hostname and $fileName for each element of the array.

I'm stuck on how to add the variables within the first foreach loop to the `$sessionsArray` array so I can then subsequently loop through that array.

Comment: In your loop, you need to check i the object has `hostname` or `serverName`, since the objects are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sessionsArray = array();
foreach($records as $key => $record){
        $sessionsArray[$key]['hostname'] = $record->hostname; 
    $sessionsArray[$key]['fileName'] = $record->fileName;
}
```

Comment: This will throw a notice about _"undefined property 'hostname'"_ on two of the three objects in the json data. Two has `serverName` and only one have `hostname`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($records as $record){
    $sessionsArray[] = [
        'hostname' => $record->hostname,
        'fileName' => $record->fileName,
    ];
}
```

And then you can do:

```
foreach($sessionsArray as $entry){
    $hostname = $entry['hostname'];
    $fileName = $entry['fileName'];
}
```

=== OR ===

```
foreach($records as $record){
    $sessionsArray[$record->hostname] = $record->fileName;
}
```

and then you can do:

```
foreach($sessionsArray as $hostname => $fileName){
//    $hostname contains the hostname
//    $filename contains filename
}
```

Just FYI, based on the JSON object you provided your code SHOULD be:

```
$hostname = $record->serverName;
$fileName = $record->fileName;
```

Comment: There is a `];` too many in the second code block. You also need to check on each iteration if the object has `hostname` or `serverName` since the objects differ.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks, the tribulations of copy/paste.  I agree with the checks, but wasn't part of the OP's question, guess he'll find out when he continues?

Comment: _"...but it wasn't part of the OP's question"_ - Sure it was. The OP asked how to extract the values from the Json data. To be able to do that, you would need to check what properties each object has (since we can see that they are inconsistent). That should definitely be a part of the answer.

Comment: Guess it's a matter of interpretation of "I'm stuck on how to add the variables within the first foreach loop to the $sessionsArray array so I can then subsequently loop through that array." ... I personally read it as "I'm stuck on how to put the variables into $sessionsArray" and not as "how do I get the values out of JSON".  Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the last key of `sessionsArray` before  every `loop` and pass that `last key` while adding to variable.

Here is example:

```
$sessionsArray = !empty($sessionsArray)?$sessionsArray:[];
$continueKey = (@array_pop(array_keys($sessionsArray)))?@array_pop(array_keys($sessionsArray))+1:0;
foreach($records as $record){
       $sessionsArray[$continueKey]['hostname'] = $record->hostname;
       $sessionsArray[$continueKey]['fileName'] = $record->fileName;

}
```